# ArcScene fails to export multipatch to 3D?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, 3d-analyst, arcscene, multipatch

I'm having a problem with the exportation in ArcScene. I want to export multipatch layer consisting of two spheres to the VRML (*.wrl). But ArcScene crushes down every time. I tried different options like JPEG texture quality etc. but it didn't work. I want to export this multipatch with a DEM. Exporting DEM alone works. But multipatch is causing some trouble.

Any ideas why?

[image: arcscene project]

Comment: It doesn't help, I know, but ArcScene is notoriously buggy.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS do yo use?

Comment: trial version of ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop .. but it happens to my colleague as well and he has a full version I guess